# Incrementing array index in SQL statement throws error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, mysqli

I want to `insert` into sql database , the items in the array. All I am doing is incrementing the index of array in `INSERT` command ( `cash[$i+1]` ) using `for` loop. But it shows an error :

> unexpected '+', expected ']'

How can I solve this problem?

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($cash_list); $i = $i+8) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Payments VALUES('$cash_list[$i]','$cash_list[$i+1]','$cash_list[$i+2]','$cash_list[$i+3]','$cash_list[$i+4]','$cash_list[$i+5]','$cash_list[$i+6]','$cash_list[$i+7]')";

    if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) 
        echo "yes";
    else
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because

```
$i+1
```

Doesn't get interpreted as math expression. It's just a string. So you would have to [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) your strings like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Payments 
        VALUES('" . $cash_list[$i] . "',
               '" . $cash_list[$i+1] . "',
               '" . $cash_list[$i+2] . "',
               '" . $cash_list[$i+3] . "',
               '" . $cash_list[$i+4] . "',
               '" . $cash_list[$i+5] . "',
               '" . $cash_list[$i+6] . "',
               '" . $cash_list[$i+7] . "'
       )";
```

Also you might want to take a look into: [`mysqli_* prepared statements`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) which is much safer!
 (Also please take the `count($cash_list)` out of your loop condition and put it into a variable and then use the variable in the condition)